# playing audio from websoket using mplayer in python delayed 4 to 5 seconds

Tags: python, websocket, pipe, delay, mplayer

I start mplayer on a different process

```
cmdline = ['mplayer', '-noconsolecontrols', '-nocache', '-']

player = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I receive the audio data from websocket and feed the audio data into mplayer by writing to the stdin of the process:

```
player.stdin.write(audiodata)
```

It works, but the audio is delayed 4 to 5 seconds.  I am pretty sure it is the mplayer causing the delay, as I can see that mplayer does not play the audio immediately, but wait until it receives quite a few batch of the audio data. I have already turn the cache off, so I suspect mplayer still need certain amount of data before it can decode?

The code are in python and runs on Ubunbtu. 
I wonder if I can have mplayer play the audio immediately once it receives it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try adding `player.stdin.flush()` right after the write. Does that help?

Comment: I did try flushing, and also tried adding '\n' at the end of each received audio data, but none of these working.